# why I'm not getting the actual state with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm getting the state to populate my form but is not the actual state, apparently it is the initial state.

```
import React from "react";
import store from "../store";

const Invoice = () => {
  console.log(store.getState().login);

    return (
    <div className="span7">
      <h4 className="title">
        <span className="text">
          <strong>Datos</strong> de facturación
        </span>
      </h4>
...
```

However, my redux chrome DevTools is showing the actual state (the right one), why the difference?
[image]

[image]

Comment: And how store looks like?...

Comment: the title suggests something is wrong with redux. it is not. when the code with `console.log` was executed (during a React render), the redux state was exactly as logged. but if you never tell React to re-render when the state changes - by using `react-redux` [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) or [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) - then this is exactly what should have been expected.

Comment: I try: import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Invoice = () => {
  const [userAuth, setUserAuth] = useState(useSelector(state => state.login)); console.log(userAuth);

but same result!

Comment: ehm, `useState(useSelector(...))`??? what are you trying to achieve, please? what it actually does, it sets the INITIAL state to the value from selector and then it will never modify the local state, because you never call `setUserAuth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide on 1 source of truth for your state - if you believe it should live in `redux`, then select the state from redux and DON'T combine it with a local `useState`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Invoice = () => {
  const userAuth = useSelector(state => state.login);
  console.log(userAuth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log current state (from redux), I think you should use [subscription](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) (`store.subscribe(...)`) and put it into `useEffect` hook.

Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = store.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(store.getState().login);
      });
  return () => { subscription() } // clear out subscription when component unmounts
},[])
```

You are seeing difference between redux dev tools and your conslole.log because with store.getState() you are getting state at it was when your component was mounted. With subscribe you are getting notified any time some action get dispatched an state get changed.

Comment: is there a reason why you propose a low level API instead of the de-facto standard `connect` or `useSelector`?

Comment: @Aprillion From question asked by post author I can't judge his reasons why he didn't use `connect` (with mapState) or `useSelector`. Connecting `Invoice` or using `useSelector` is certainly better than using low level API, but question acctually started with low level API and why it does't work. So I am suggesting same level API which do what he wants to accomplish.

Comment: hm, I see your reasons. I don't agree - even if you want to assume high level of competency of the low-reputation user who asked the question, why would you assume all visitors of this public Q&A page will know enough to recognize your assumption? why not provide both solutions - the one you think is the best and then the workaround if the best-in-general is not applicable in a particular situation?